# Change date format in googlefinance (historical)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-finance

I have a google sheets formula to get an historical rate for a determined currency pair:

```
GOOGLEFINANCE("CURRENCY:"&A2,"price",DATE(YEAR(B3),MONTH(B3),DAY(B3)),DATE(YEAR(B4),MONTH(B4),DAY(B4)),"DAILY")
```

It outputs the date as follows :

```
Date    
12/06/2019 23:58:00
13/06/2019 23:58:00 
14/06/2019 23:58:00 
15/06/2019 23:58:00
16/06/2019 23:58:00
```

When I need to have the date formatted as `12/06/2019 00:00:00`, getting rid of the H:M:s

I tried a query in order to format the date column under the required format:

```
=query(GOOGLEFINANCE("CURRENCY:"&A2,"price",DATE(YEAR(B3),MONTH(B3),DAY(B3)),DATE(YEAR(B4),MONTH(B4),DAY(B4)),"DAILY"),"select Col1, Col2 FORMAT Col1 'YYYY-MM-DD 00:00:00'")
```

the column is reformatted but the underlying date stays with the incorrect hour:minutes:seconds number

I could add a third column with an `ArrayFormula` to get the first column formatted correctly, but I would like to keep the formula in a more convenient 2 columns format.

Comment: Why don't you just use `left(yourfinanceformulahere,10)` to get just the date.

Comment: How do you use a `left` formula inside `googlefinance`?

Comment: Use it outside.

Comment: You can remove the time (decimal part of date) by doing `=INT(XY)`, the format the cell as date